# Microsoft Sentinel searching for a string in raw payload

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to find out if there is a way in Microsoft Sentinel to perform a search across all Data Connectors and all logs.
This is a similar functionality to that provided by, for example, IBM QRadar, where it is possible to perform a search across all Log Sources and a payload overview of all saved logs in their raw syslog form.

AQL query format in QRadar that I would like to do in Sentinel:

SELECT UTF8(payload) FROM events WHERE UTF8(payload) ILIKE 'search string' LAST 24 HOURS

This is a very useful feature, especially when back-analyzing logs and debugging rules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `search` operator.  `search` operator is substantially less efficient than table-specific and column-specific text filtering.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator?pivots=azuremonitor

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I've looked at this possibility, but I'm still not sure if it's an analogy like "payload contains" in QRadar, where the search is performed on raw syslog data that is not parsed in any way by SIEM. This makes it possible to verify that the error did not occur, eg due to incorrect regex, encoding, etc. And I'm not sure if this "search" function will really find it for me as I don't know what data "search" is using. Regards.